# How to maintain date format when after applying function

Tags: r, date, mutate

I have dataframe with a poorly formatted date information.

```
date = c("18102016", "11102017", "4052017", "18102018", "3102018")
df <- data.frame(date = date, x1 = 1:5, x2 = rep(1,5))
```

I have already written the function `fix_date_all()` which does the proper formatting when applied to the vector `df$date`

```
fix_date_all<- function(date){
  fix_date <- function(d) {
    if (nchar(d) != 8) d <- paste0("0", d)
    
    dd <- d %>% substr(1,2)
    mm <- d %>% substr(3,4)
    yyyy <- d %>% substr(5,8)
    
    d <- paste0(dd, ".", mm, ".", yyyy) %>% as.Date("%d.%m.%Y")
    
    d
  }
  
  lapply(date, fix_date)
}

fix_date_all(df$date)
```

Now I would like to transform this variable to a proper date format using a tidyverse like style:

```
df %>% mutate(across(date, fix_date_all))
```

However, when using it in a tidyverse style, the date gets screwed up.

```
   date x1 x2
1 17092  1  1
2 17450  2  1
3 17290  3  1
4 17822  4  1
5 17807  5  1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A second option would be to get rid of `lapply` and rewrite your function using e.g. `string::str_pad`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

fix_date_all<- function(date){
  date %>%  
    stringr::str_pad(width = 8, pad = "0") %>% 
    as.Date(format = "%d%m%Y")
}

fix_date_all(df$date)
#> [1] "2016-10-18" "2017-10-11" "2017-05-04" "2018-10-18" "2018-10-03"

df %>% 
  mutate(across(date, fix_date_all))
#>         date x1 x2
#> 1 2016-10-18  1  1
#> 2 2017-10-11  2  1
#> 3 2017-05-04  3  1
#> 4 2018-10-18  4  1
#> 5 2018-10-03  5  1
```

Answer (score 3):

The output is a `list` from the `lapply` call.

```
fix_date_all(df$date)
[[1]]
[1] "2016-10-18"

[[2]]
[1] "2017-10-11"

[[3]]
[1] "2017-05-04"

[[4]]
[1] "2018-10-18"

[[5]]
[1] "2018-10-03"
```

We need to flatten it with `c`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(date = fix_date_all(date) %>%
   do.call(c, .))
```

-output

```
        date x1 x2
1 2016-10-18  1  1
2 2017-10-11  2  1
3 2017-05-04  3  1
4 2018-10-18  4  1
5 2018-10-03  5  1
```

Or in the newer version of `purrr`, use `list_c`

```
library(purrr)
df %>% 
    mutate(date = fix_date_all(date)  %>% list_c)
        date x1 x2
1 2016-10-18  1  1
2 2017-10-11  2  1
3 2017-05-04  3  1
4 2018-10-18  4  1
5 2018-10-03  5  1
```

Comment: is `do.call(c, .))` necessary or would `unlist()` do the trick?

Comment: @DanY You could check the output `fix_date_all(df$date) |> unlist()`

Comment: Just to follow up -- `unlist()` does not preserve formatting, so you need do in fact need  `do.call()` as per your example

Answer (score 2):

The `sprintf` will prepend with a 0 if short and then we convert to Date.  No packages are used.

```
as.Date(sprintf("%08d", as.numeric(date)), "%d%m%Y")
## [1] "2016-10-18" "2017-10-11" "2017-05-04" "2018-10-18" "2018-10-03"
```

Note that it is vectorized and works within `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(date) %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(sprintf("%08d", as.numeric(date)), "%d%m%Y"))
##         date
## 1 2016-10-18
## 2 2017-10-11
## 3 2017-05-04
## 4 2018-10-18
## 5 2018-10-03
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `lapply` use `sapply`. But at the same time, just use vectorized `ifelse` as shown below:

```
fix_date_all<- function(d){
    d <- ifelse(nchar(d) != 8, paste0("0", d), d)
    as.Date(d, "%d%m%Y")
}

df %>% 
    mutate(date = fix_date_all(date))

        date x1 x2
1 2016-10-18  1  1
2 2017-10-11  2  1
3 2017-05-04  3  1
4 2018-10-18  4  1
5 2018-10-03  5  1
>
```